# Пытаюсь декодировать пакет закодированный с помощью socket.io

Tags: typescript, socket.io

Протокол стандартного кодирования пакетов, если не использовать другой, описан тут https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-protocol

Примеры работы парсера тут https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-parser

Что я делаю: Я перехватываю вот эти данные у веб-сокета (42["auth",{"session":"a:4:{s:10:"session_id";s:32:"c7a4e4dbd7a319b7b331b4f1857e83e2";s:10:"ip_address";s:15:"1.1.1.1";s:10:"user_agent";s:111:"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";s:13:"last_activity";i:1706693323;}5c1b5116a2239f38014cd50829af459d","isDemo":0,"uid":10000000,"platform":2}]) которые закодированы с помощью socket.io

Пытаюсь их декодировать и получить json объект но не получается ;(

```html
var parser = require('socket.io-parser');
var decoder = new parser.Decoder();
const auth: string = '42["auth",{"session":"a:4:{s:10:\"session_id\";s:32:\"c7a4e4dbd7a319b7b331b4f1857e83e2\";s:10:\"ip_address\";s:15:\"1.1.1.1\";s:10:\"user_agent\";s:111:\"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36\";s:13:\"last_activity\";i:1706693323;}5c1b5116a2239f38014cd50829af459d","isDemo":0,"uid":10000000,"platform":2}]';

decoder.add(auth);

decoder.on('decoded', function(decodedPacket: any) {
    ??? ничего тут не происходит, событие 'decoded' не срабатывает
    console.log(decodedPacket.type);
});
```

Подскажите в чём моя ошибка?

Comment: попробуй добавлять обработчик **до** того, как вызываешь `.add`